# не отображаются кириллицы на jsp странице

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, locale, локализация

В приложении есть локализация en/ru, файл localization.properties находится в папке webapp/WEB-INF/classes.
В файле localization_en.properties : local.index.register=Register. 
В файле localization_ru.properties : local.index.register=Зарегистрироваться

Есть класс:

```html
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {

    private String code;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) {
        code = fConfig.getInitParameter("character-encoding");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String codeRequest = request.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (code != null && !code.equalsIgnoreCase(codeRequest)) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(code);
            response.setCharacterEncoding(code);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        code = null;
    }
}
```

и в web.xml соответствено пишу

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
```

и для фильтра:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>controller.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>character-encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

На странице index.jsp прописываю

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:bundle basename="localization">
    <fmt:message key="local.index.register" var="register"/>
</fmt:bundle>
```

и обращаюсь к переменной

```
<h5>${register}</h5>
```

При запуске приложения на странице символы ÐÐ°ÑÐµÐ³Ð¸ÑÑÑÐ¸ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°ÑÑÑÑ

Как сделать, чтобы они отображались нормально? Использую Intellij idea, ApacheTomcat, ОС Ubuntu, браузер Chrome

Comment: файл ru.properties в какой-то другой кодировке, не utf-8?

Comment: файл в кодировке utf-8, в настройках intellij в File Encodig тоже utf-8, и стоит галочка напротив Transparent native-to asccii conversion

Comment: Если просто в файле index.jsp задавать <h5>Текст</h5>, то кириллица отображается, не работает именно из файла .properties

Comment: Попробуйте в jsp в первой строке добавить `pageEncoding`: <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

Comment: а в браузере смотрели заголовок Content-Type? Там кодировка win-1252?

Comment: еще такие логи, может они что значат?   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TravelAgency ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ TravelAgency ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

Comment: @alex, в браузере content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8, Content-Language: ru-RU